# Multi-Evironment config bootstrap above webroot on a single server

Tags: focus-lab-master-config, staging-server

I'm working on a project that only has one server to work with. That means the production and development server are the same and development is a sub domain (dev.example.com). In the past when I've run into this it hasn't been an issue to use the Focus Labs multi environment bootstrap setup. I just put both system folders above webroot:

- Pulblic_html

  - www.example.com

    - system
  - dev.example.com

    - system

However on this project we want to put the system folder above webroot:

- system
- Public_html

  - www.example.com

That presents a problem when putting dev on the same server. They would both point to the same folder above webroot. Is there a way to have the bootstrap file look for a different system folder above webroot?

- system
- system_dev
- public_html

  - www.example.com
  - dev.example.com

I trie hacking around the config file, but didn't have any luck. Anyone do this? It seems like a pretty common scenario people would encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, though not ideal, would be to put a conditional in the index.php and admin.php files:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case "www.example.com" :
        $system_path = "../system";
    break;

    case "dev.example.com" :
        $system_path = "../system_dev";
    break;

    default :
        $system_path = "../system";
    break;
}
```

Comment: I figured something like this would be possible. I'll check with the hosting company first to see what is possible. Then give this a shot if that doesn't work out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately it comes down to your hosting company and how much control they have over mapping the domain's web root.

I'd ask your host if you can re-map the production domain to point to /public_html/public. Same with your development domain, have it mapped to dev_html/public. So your setup will look like this:

- dev_html

  - system
  - public
- public_html

  - system
  - public

Or, another option would be:

- public_html

  - www.example.com

    - public
    - system
  - dev.example.com

    - public
    - system

That way you can keep your above-root assets separate and tidy.

Comment: It is Bluehost, I'll check with them. Thanks.

Comment: I have done it using the second option quite often. Either that or I set up a subdomain of one of my own domain names and use a different server.